# ExecuteUpdate stuck with insert sql in Java

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, openedge

I am using "com.ddtek.jdbc.openedge.OpenEdgeDriver" to execute sql queries in java. Because application running with progress DB. I execute insert sql statement as follows.

```
String sqlString="INSERT INTO PUB.hrlh (frmaid, grgrid, kwalid, klrnid, varid, rkeus, rolhid, genrol, prdcid, indate, levrid,"
            + " levrnaam, initlengte, lengte, efflengte, breedte, verfbad, krimpl, krimpb, prijs, barcode, specif, Rek, kolom, nivo, "
            + "pos, palet, edoms, diphid, seizid, stuknr, ref, swprt, beshid, beslid, volgnr, reflevnota, crdate, crtime, cruscd, alfa, "
            + "prijsfrm, mntnid, levnota, pakhid, snyhid, intbarc, divhid, snijln, reden, crsrt, vlgnr,"
            + " hcruscd,hcrtime,chdate,hcrdate) VALUES(" + roll.getFrmaid()+ ",'"+ roll.getGrgrid()+"','"+ roll.getKwalid()+"','"+ roll.getKlrnid()+
            "',"+ roll.getVarid()+","+ roll.getRkeus()+","+ roll.getRolhid()+","+roll.getGenrol()+",'"+ roll.getPrdcid()+ "',"+(roll.getIndate()==null?null:"{ d '"+ roll.getIndate()+"' }")+ 
            ", "+ roll.getLevrid()+",'"+ SystemPara.replaceApostrophe(roll.getLevrnaam())+"',"+ roll.getInitlengte()+","+ roll.getLengte()+","+ roll.getEfflengte()+
            ","+ roll.getBreedte()+",'"+ roll.getVerfbad()+"',"+ roll.getKrimpl()+","+ roll.getKrimpb()+","+ roll.getPrijs()+","+ roll.getBarcode()+
            ",'"+ roll.getSpecif()+"','"+ roll.getRek()+"',"+ roll.getKolom()+","+roll.getNivo()+",'"+ roll.getPos()+"','"+ roll.getPalet()+"','"+ SystemPara.replaceApostrophe(edoms)+
            "',"+ roll.getDiphid()+",'"+ roll.getSeizid()+"','"+ roll.getStuknr()+"','"+roll.getRef()+"',"+SystemPara.getIntFromBoolean(roll.getSwprt())+","+roll.getBeshid()+","+ roll.getBeslid()+
            ","+ roll.getVolgnr()+",'"+ roll.getReflevnota()+"',{ d '"+ SystemPara.getNewDate()+"'},"+ SystemPara.getNewTime().longValue()+",'"+ roll.getCruscd()+"','"+ roll.getAlfa()+
            "',"+ roll.getPrijsfrm()+","+ roll.getMntnid()+",'"+ roll.getLevnota()+"',"+ roll.getPakhid()+","+ roll.getSnyhid()+","+ roll.getIntbarc()+
            ","+ roll.getDivhid()+","+ roll.getSnijln()+",'"+ roll.getReden()+"','"+ roll.getCrsrt()+"',"+ roll.getVlgnr()+
            ",'"+ roll.getHcruscd()+"',"+roll.getHcrtime() +","+ (roll.getChdate()==null?null:"{ d '"+roll.getChdate()+"'}") +","+
             (roll.getHcrdate()==null?null:"{ d '"+roll.getHcrdate()+"'}")+")";

Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
stmt.executeUpdate(sqlString);
```

But this statement not execute and stuck at the executeUpdate() method.

I found the reason for this as "edoms" field in above query has 750 character string. "edoms" field contains following text.

```
    Dear Ruwan,

We have received these 50mtr free of charge, so please enter this fabric as sample.

Brgds
Stefka

Van: abcd silva 
Verzonden: woensdag 11 mei 2016 9:38
Aan: ’ruwan’; ’chandima’
CC: Frank Vermeulen; ’Serge’; ’Asanji’; ’samanthika’; ’patrice’; ’Udaya’; ’osanda’
Onderwerp: RE: SO prices Intex

Dear saman,

I am checking this, reverting back asap.

Brgds
Bert

Van: ruwan [mailto:saman@test.com] 
Verzonden: woensdag 11 mei 2016 8:27
Aan: ’saman’; Bert ven; ’chandima’
CC: Frank Vermeulen; ’Serge’; ’Asanji’; ’samanthika’; ’patrice’; ’Udaya’; ’osanda’
Onderwerp: RE: SO prices Intex

Dear stefka

We need to create GRN for this received roll. If you want to make payment for this, pls. mail me invoice for thi
```

I changed above query with prepared statements as follows. But not solve above issue.

```
String sql="INSERT INTO PUB.hrlh (frmaid, grgrid, kwalid, klrnid, varid, rkeus, rolhid, genrol, prdcid, indate, levrid,"
                    + " levrnaam, initlengte, lengte, efflengte, breedte, verfbad, krimpl, krimpb, prijs, barcode, specif, Rek, kolom, nivo, "
                    + "pos, palet, edoms, diphid, seizid, stuknr, ref, swprt, beshid, beslid, volgnr, reflevnota, crdate, crtime, cruscd, alfa, "
                    + "prijsfrm, mntnid, levnota, pakhid, snyhid, intbarc, divhid, snijln, reden, crsrt, vlgnr,"
                    + " hcruscd,hcrtime,chdate,hcrdate) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?," 
                    + "?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";               
            PreparedStatement pt = con.getConnection().prepareStatement(sql);
            pt.setInt(1, roll.getFrmaid());
            pt.setString(2, roll.getGrgrid());
            pt.setString(3, roll.getKwalid());
            pt.setString(4, roll.getKlrnid());
            pt.setInt(5, roll.getVarid());
            pt.setInt(6, roll.getRkeus());
            pt.setInt(7, roll.getRolhid());
            pt.setInt(8, roll.getGenrol());
            pt.setString(9, roll.getPrdcid());
            pt.setDate(10, null);
            pt.setInt(11, roll.getLevrid());
            pt.setString(12, "Test1");
            pt.setDouble(13, roll.getInitlengte());
            pt.setDouble(14, roll.getLengte());
            pt.setDouble(15, roll.getEfflengte());
            pt.setDouble(16, roll.getBreedte());        
            pt.setString(17, roll.getVerfbad());
            pt.setDouble(18, roll.getKrimpl());
            pt.setDouble(19, roll.getKrimpb());
            pt.setDouble(20, roll.getPrijs());
            pt.setInt(21, roll.getBarcode());
            pt.setString(22, roll.getSpecif());
            pt.setString(23, roll.getRek());
            pt.setInt(24, roll.getKolom());
            pt.setInt(25, roll.getNivo());
            pt.setString(26, roll.getPos());
            pt.setString(27, roll.getPalet());
            pt.setString(28, roll.getEdoms());
            pt.setInt(29, roll.getDiphid());    
            pt.setString(30, roll.getSeizid()); 
            pt.setString(31, roll.getStuknr());         
            pt.setString(32, roll.getRef());            
            pt.setBoolean(33, roll.getSwprt());         
            pt.setInt(34, roll.getBeshid());            
            pt.setInt(35, roll.getBeslid());            
            pt.setInt(36, roll.getVolgnr());            
            pt.setString(37, roll.getReflevnota());         
            pt.setDate(38, null);   
            pt.setLong(39, SystemPara.getNewTime().longValue());            
            pt.setString(40, roll.getCruscd());         
            pt.setString(41, roll.getAlfa());           
            pt.setDouble(42, roll.getPrijsfrm());           
            pt.setInt(43, roll.getMntnid());            
            pt.setString(44, roll.getLevnota());            
            pt.setInt(45, roll.getPakhid());            
            pt.setInt(46, roll.getSnyhid());            
            pt.setDouble(47, roll.getIntbarc());            
            pt.setInt(48, roll.getDivhid());
            pt.setInt(49, roll.getSnijln());
            pt.setString(50, roll.getReden());
            pt.setString(51, roll.getCrsrt());
            pt.setInt(52, roll.getVlgnr());
            pt.setString(53, roll.getHcruscd());
            pt.setInt(54, (roll.getHcrtime()==null?0:roll.getHcrtime()));
            pt.setDate(55, null);
            pt.setDate(56, null);       
            pt.executeUpdate();
```

I did not get any exception. Execution stuck at the executeUpdate(). That's the issue.

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Sorry, change your code first. Use PreparedStatement. IMHO your code is a huge security issue and should not be discussed here further.

Comment: You said "I found the reason for this as "edoms" field in above query has 750 character string." Can you give more details on this? How did you conclude? What version of OpenEdge is it? What OS is it? Have you tried querying "edmos" field length from SQL?